# Update two databases as an atomic operation in NoSQL

Tags: java, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, atomic, nosql

This question has been bugging my mind for quite a long time.

Database : Amazon DynamoDB

Tables : MasterRegistrationTable(A) and RegistrationType1Table(B)

Scenario : We have a web-service. The user sends the data making a call to some ReST API of our service. Now we need to do a PUT/UPDATE operation. Now here is the catch. We need to first do that operation in table B, and since we have a master table that aggregates data from all the slaves we have to do same operation in A. How can we ensure that data is 
1. Not Lost
2. Entry is made either to both or to None.

There could be various point of failures

Scenario1 : Table B gets updated, update to Table A fails.

Scenario2 : We record the preImage from table B. Do an update to table B. Then try to update on table A but it fails. So we rollback to preImage, but that rollback step fails(incidentally that rollback is also a DELETE operation)

Scenario3 : We introduce a Queue in between/start/end. Introducing the queue in between wont guarantee the consistent state of DBs since data might be intact in queue but only one DB (B) is updated and the other not. Any query to A wont return the result. Having data pushed to queue if an operation fails also introduces the fact that pushing data to queue also fails.

I think u get the idea.

I want to know how something like a transaction in handled in NoSQL world. Is such a design bad? Should we never have a scenario where we have to update two DBs? What if we have one? How do you guarantee that your system is not in inconsistent state when there are possibilities of systems failing(application failure, network outages etc)?

Comment: You may want to look into "eventual consistency". Doing this actually atomically is a *very* complicated and expensive process.

Comment: I want to know something more. I know what is "eventual consistency" and that is something that Scenario3 gives right. Hoping to get some detailed response.